# Check if string ends with the given target strings | javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, substr

I am trying to write javascript code that will test if the end of the first string is the same as the target, return true. Else, return false. must use .substr() to obtain the result.

```
function end(str, target) {
myArray = str.split();
//Test if end of string and the variables are the same
if (myArray.subsrt(-1) == target) {
 return true;
}
else {
 return false;
}
}

end('Bastian', 'n');
```

Comment: Note that you can do this more concisely with a regular expression. But you said it must use substr() so the below answers are good.

Answer (score 8):

try:

```
function end(str, target) {
   return str.substring(str.length-target.length) == target;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

In new browsers you can use: [string.prototype.endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith), but polyfill is needed for IE (you can use https://polyfill.io that include the polyfill and don't return any content for modern browsers, it's also usefull for other things related to IE).

Comment: That worked. May you give details of your code so I may understand. Thank you.

Comment: @JeffCollins it get substring of the string, if you put single number it return from the number to the end. so it substring that many characters from end str.length as the length of the target. and check if that the same as the target.

Answer (score 1):

As of ES6 you can use `endsWith()` with strings. For example:

```js
let mystring = 'testString';
//should output true
console.log(mystring.endsWith('String'));
//should output true
console.log(mystring.endsWith('g'));
//should output false
console.log(mystring.endsWith('test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
 function end(str, target) {
  var strLen = str.length;
  var tarLen = target.length;
  var rest = strLen -tarLen;
  strEnd = str.substr(rest);

  if (strEnd == target){
    return true;
     }else{
  return false;
     }  
 return str;
}
end('Bastian', 'n');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
function end(str, target) {
    return str.substring(- (target.length)) == target;
}
```