# proccesing of two strings using Substring(), And Substr()

Tags: javascript

lets say we have to strings `var first = "hi my name is this";` and `var second = "this";` using  Substring() and/or Substr() or both string methods I want to check to see if the second string matches the ending of first (I know about String.prototype.endsWith()). how can that be done? thanks

so far I have this but its wrong

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  // calculate the length of second string
  // remove the end of the first string (same amount) with the first string
  //compare the two
  var secondStringLen = target.length;
  var firstStringLen = str.length;
  var firstStringEnding = str.substring(secondStringLen+1, -1);

  return firstStringEnding;
}

confirmEnding("abcaqwexefg", "efg");
```

Comment: `if first.split(" ").pop() == second`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated my question. and could not find a similar question on the web

Comment: Simple as this `if(first.endsWith(second))` !

Comment: Your function is returning a string. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah but I could not find anything regarding these methods initiating from the end instead of the beginning

Comment: @T.J.Crowder damn I guess I did not phrase my search query correctly

Comment: The answer is [right there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30154019/5459839)  in the other reference.

Comment: @dadadodo: It happens to us all. FWIW, tags and the "is" thing (in my search I used "is:question") can help. Or Google with site:stackoverflow.com (unsurprisingly, Google's search of SO is better than SO's). BTW, you can just delete this question. Enjoy your JS! :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this !

```js
var first = "hi my name is this";
var second = "this";

function confirmEnding(str1, str2) {
  var l1 = str1.length,
    l2 = str2.length;

  var str = str1.substring(l1 - l2);

  if (str == str2)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("abcaqwexefg", "efg"));
console.log(confirmEnding(first, second));
```

Comment: You did not read the question well enough. And this is a duplicate question anyway...